# Passing child function into parent function, child function then uses parent function variables?

Tags: javascript, function

```
var thisfunc = function() {
 potato++;
}
var obj = function(myfunc) {
   var potato = 12;
   myfunc(); 
}
obj(thisfunc);
//Potato is now 13
```

-- (one way I figured it could be done)

```
var thisfunc = function(mypotato) {
 mypotato++;
}
var obj = function(myfunc) {
   var potato = 12;
   myfunc(potato); 
}
obj(thisfunc);
//Potato is now 13
```

What are possible ways for me to pass potato into 'myfunc', I'm assuming passing potato down into myfunc as a parameter would do it, HOWEVER I am hoping there's a way myfunc() can access its parent properties or would it be unable to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options.

1. Declare `potato` outside of the parent function.
2. Make `potato` a global variable.
3. Pass it in as you have already demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has local scopes and no pass-by-reference calls, so this is quite impossible.

The only thing you could do is nest your two functions, so that the child function has access to the parent's variables through closure:

```
function obj() {
    function myfunc() {
        potato++;
    }
    var potato = 12;
    myfunc();
    console.log(potato); // 13
}
obj();
```

If you don't want to do the nesting, or really need `thisfunc` to be dynamic, all you can do is to build an object and access its properties instead of the local variables - an object which you can also pass around.

```
function thisfunc(x) {
    x.potato++;
}
function obj(myfunc) {
    var scope = {
        potato: 12
    };
    myfunc(scope);
    console.log(scope.potato); // 13
}
obj(thisfunc);
```